# How to write shell script that filter for lines and count them?

Tags: bash, parsing, shell, text, scripting

I have a text file like this:

```
Apple
Orange
Orange
Banana
Banana
Orange
Banana
Orange
Apple
Orange
```

I want to produce the following output after running a bash shell script:

```
Apple: 2
Orange: 5
Banana: 3
```

It's pretty standard stuff if I use a full blown language like Java/C++ etc but what is the quickest way to do it with a shell script/command line?

Comment: @Dennis: Or combining a ton of internet fiction (with author location information) with a list of fruits to do a study on fruit prevalence vs. region! Aren't you curious?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sort $FILE | uniq -c
```

will give you

```
2 Apple
3 Banana
5 Orange
```

Comment: and to reformat, you can use perl as NawaMan said, or sed: `... | sed -r 's/ *([0-9])+ *(.*)/\2: \1/'` (the `-r` switches it to extended regex, and the substitution is the same as NawaMan's without the unnecessary brackets).

Comment: agree with this as best, because it's likey that the user is flexible on output format.  Requirements are often agreed upon after a dialog has started.

Answer (score 4):

sort filename  | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 ": " $1 }'

Comment: I am super-sorry about the -1 I apparently gave you - just a misclick; I immediately tried to fix it and it tells me it's too old.

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses only one tool: awk

```
$ awk '{count[$0]++} END {for (c in count) {print c ": " count[c]}} ' count.txt
Orange: 5
Banana: 3
Apple: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
uniq -c $FILE | perl -pe 's|[ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]*(.*)|\2: \1|'
```

This will format it to the way to specified. You can add '| sort' at the end the sort it too.

**EDIT:** As points out in the comment, I make a mistake about uniq so here is the corrected one.

```
sort $FILE | uniq -c | perl -pe 's|[ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]*(.*)|\2: \1|'
```

Sorry for the problem.

Comment: `uniq` checks for consecutive identical lines. You must sort the list first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I mostly used to already sorted data so I forgot about that.